# Behavior. Зависимость SearchView от BottomSheet

Tags: android

Нужно чтобы `SearchView` уходила наверх при движении `BottomSheet`.

**Скриншоты**:

[image: Screen1]
[image: Screen2]

Пытался добавить `layout_anchor` и `layout_anchorGravity` для `SearchView` и писал `CoordinatorLayout.Behavior`. Но выпадает `java.lang.RuntimeException: This graph contains cyclic dependencies`. Подскажите, как можно реализовать движение SearchView вверх синхронно с BottomSheet?

Comment: Как вариант можно поставить слушатель на выдвигание `BottomSheet` и скрывать поиск при начале выдвигания. Можно поставить на конец выдвигания. А `BottomSheet` до конца открывается?

Comment: @Flippy, `BottomSheet` выдвигается не до конца, а как показано на втором скриншоте. Буду со слушателем экспериментировать

Comment: Берите высоту экрана без статусбара и навбара, берите высоту панели поиска вместе с маргинами/паддингами. Вычисляйте высоту `экран минус поиск` и ее отношение к высоте экрана от 0 до 1. Повесьте слушатель на `BottomSheet` и когда `offset` дойдет до нужного значения применяйте `offset` для сдвига поиска (например, через `setTranslationY`).